# Pirate Language Pack

Tags: magento-1, localisation, language, language-package

I'm looking for a Magento language pack, like Facebook's Pirate Language option, that is humorous. My Google-fu is failing me.

Pirate is preferable.

---

## Update

A pirate language pack been created and is now hosted on Github:

https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_PirateLang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely none. But let's build one.

I will create a bootstrap and github repository and will post more information here.

**UPDATE:**

After quick talk with my rubber duck I'm confused if this language pack will be used by anyone. So either tell me that I'm wrong and we will kick off this project or more appropriate **solution is to make a pirate translation within `translate.csv` file of your theme**.

Comment: I was planning on building one if it didn't exist - but I wanted to make sure that there wasn't some obscure translation out there already. I'm excited to contribute!

Comment: Why bootstrap? You don't talk about twitters bootstrap - you are talking about kick off data?

Comment: Please see my update. (@FabianBlechschmidt, I ment the bootstrap of the project, not Twitter Bootstrap).

Comment: I would like to see a full language pack translation - e.g. an extension to the CLDR in Zend that provides language and (maybe currency?!) options - different dialects, etc. I wanted something that looked pretty feature-rich and was whole-hog, so why don't we go whole-hog?!

Comment: All admin modules, etc. Translate ALL THE THINGS. ARRRRR.

Comment: Finally available -  https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_PirateLang